# iPad Zoom Scale Detection

Tags: html, ipad, menu, zooming

I'm trying to find a way to detect how zoomed in someone is on a web app so that when they click to pull up a menu, the menu stays the same size regardless of the zoom. To do that, I need to be able to scale the size of the menu appropriately relative to the zoom. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Looking to answer this very question, after much digging around.  Setting a bounty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, all `UIWebView` has as a `UIScrollView` subview. So, in order to get it you could do the following:

```
for (UIView * v in [_webView subviews]) {

    if ([v isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
        UIScrollView * s = (UIScrollView*)v;
        // use the scrollview
    }

}
```

After that you can use the `UIScrollView` to find out the zoom scale. Unfortunately, the property `zoomScale` doesn't tell us, in this case, what we want, but we can use the `contentSize` and the `frame` of the scrollView, as the following:

```
CGFloat zoomScale = s.contentSize.width / s.frame.size.width;
```

After that, I suppose you want to tell your javascript code about this zoomScale. You could use the following code:

```
[_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"yourJSZoomScaleVar = %f;", zoomScale]];
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Sorry, I know that I was looking for it in the context of an actual Web page.  Further research suggests that it will be some derivation of window.innerWidth/screen.width.  Will have a chance to look at it further tomorrow.